# dbt - If there a macro like { % if is _incremental () %} that will allow me to run a block of code on the initial creation of the object?

Tags: dbt

dbt - If there a macro like { % if is _incremental () %} that will allow me to run a block of code on the initial creation of the object?

Also, where is a good resource to learn about existing macros in dbt?

Comment: What do you mean by "initial creation"? Other than incremental materializations, dbt drops and re-creates most database objects every time it runs

Comment: Maybe referring to a pre-hook? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook